# Getting blank view on ViewPager-utilizing Tab Layout

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-tablayout

I'm trying to create a tab layout with three tabs showing image and a text. Unfortunately, the tabs do not display anything and I can't find anything on Logcat regarding the errors.

Here's my main code :

```
public class JavaTradHouse extends AppCompatActivity {
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_java_trad_house);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpagerTradHouses);

    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.AddFragment(new FragmentJoglo(), "Joglo Traditional House");
    adapter.AddFragment(new FragmentSukuTengger(), "Suku Tengger Traditional House");
    adapter.AddFragment(new FragmentTogogAnjing(), "Togog Anjing Traditional House");

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

}
}
```

And here is my ViewPager adapter class code :

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

   private final List<Fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
   private final List<String> fragmentListTitles = new ArrayList<>();


   public ViewPagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return fragmentListTitles.get(position);
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

           return fragmentList.get(position);
           /* switch (position)
            {
                case 1 :
                    FragmentJoglo  joglofragment = new FragmentJoglo();
                    return joglofragment;
                case 2 :
                    FragmentSukuTengger sukutenggerfragment = new FragmentSukuTengger();
                    return sukutenggerfragment;
                case 3 :
                    FragmentTogogAnjing togoganjingfragment = new FragmentTogogAnjing();
                    return togoganjingfragment;
                default :
                    return null;

            }*/ // Turning this one into a comment in case this method works
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return fragmentList.size();
        }
        public void AddFragment(Fragment fragment, String Title){
           fragmentList.add(fragment);
           fragmentListTitles.add(Title);
        }
    }
```

I'm new to tab layouts due to the fact that not much references from my country actually talks about it in-depth. Anything I can do here? As I said earlier, logcat doesn't show anything as it is a successful program execution.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this ViewPagerAdaper**

```
class ViewPagerAdapter(manager: FragmentManager) : FragmentPagerAdapter(manager) {
    private val mFragmentList = ArrayList<androidx.fragment.app.Fragment>()
    private val mFragmentTitleList = ArrayList<String>()

    override fun getItem(position: Int): androidx.fragment.app.Fragment {
        return mFragmentList[position]
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return mFragmentList.size
    }

    fun addFragment(fragment: androidx.fragment.app.Fragment, title: String) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment)
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title)
    }

    fun addFragment(title: String) {
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title)
    }

    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {
        return mFragmentTitleList[position]
    }

    fun getFragmentList(): ArrayList<androidx.fragment.app.Fragment> {
        return mFragmentList
    }
}
```

**and here is main code for Viewpager Adapter
call setupviewpager() method in onCreate().**

```
private fun setupViewPager() {
        try {
            adapter = ViewPagerAdapter(childFragmentManager)
            val customersFragment = CustomerListFragment()
            val suppliersFragment = SupplierListFragment()
            adapter.addFragment(customersFragment, getString(R.string.str_customers))
            adapter.addFragment(suppliersFragment, getString(R.string.str_suppliers))
            viewPager?.adapter = adapter
            tabs?.setupWithViewPager(viewPager!!)
            onTabSelectedListener()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

    private fun onTabSelectedListener(): TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {

        return object : TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {
            override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {
                viewPager.currentItem = tab.position
            }
            override fun onTabUnselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {

            }
            override fun onTabReselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {

            }
        }
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == 101 && data != null) {
            if (viewPager.currentItem == 0) {
                val customerListFragment = adapter.instantiateItem(
                    viewPager,
                    viewPager.currentItem
                ) as CustomerListFragment

            } else if (viewPager.currentItem == 0) {
                val customerListFragment = adapter.instantiateItem(
                    viewPager,
                    viewPager.currentItem
                ) as SupplierListFragment

            }
        }
    }
```

I have created with customerFragment or suppliersFragment, replace your fragment.

Comment: Appreciate the help, but the application you were commenting on the second column differs with mine, sadly. Or is the main function call for the adapter somewhere in the second column of the code?